# how to get pretty urls in hapi js

Tags: javascript, node.js, friendly-url, hapi.js, pretty-urls

I have my server.js file working. at localhost:8080 it will serve the file i give it from the the corresponding url name like so `http://localhost:8080/about.html`, as long as the file exists in public/pages. I'm wondering if I can somehow set a wildcard to leave of extensions for all html files in the url so that I don't have to individually specify each file as an alias in the routes like - `['about','about.html']`.

Here is my working code -

```
'use strict';

const Path = require('path');
const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    port: Number(process.argv[2] || 8080),
    host: 'localhost'
});
server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: 'public/pages',
                listing: true
            }
        },
        config: {
            state: {
              parse: false, // parse and store in request.state
              failAction: 'ignore' // may also be 'ignore' or 'log'
            }
        }

    });

    server.start((err) => {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you building api and ui app on same project ? I would recommend to leave api in hapi and host the UI app directly on nginx and apply routing at nginx level

Comment: @georoot I am just sandboxing right now so mostly just doing a ui. I will probably add an api with mongodb later on. I have heard that nginx can do this, I am not very familiar with nginx though, it is a little over my head 8/

Comment: I would recommend you look into a server. Can be nginx or apache... many alternative out there. Also event for prototyping UI, use grunt or something with live reload. Finally if you have separate api, keep both data pane and control pane different. This way it would be easier for you in future to put the UI behind CDN or something :)